# como mostrar un mensaje si la query no se realizar y si se realiza tambien

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

es que quiero mostrar el mensaje correspondiente, tengo un formulario que agreaga el registro en la tabla (si hace el insert), en la tabla del cliente tengo un campo unico el "nume_documento" y pues si por formulario si lo ingreso repetido es logico que no hara el insert por tanto quiero devolver un mensaje de que no se realizó y viseversa.

la cosa es que me tira el mensaje, pero no se recarga la pagina (necesario para que se refresque la tabla donde los muestro), tanto para cuando no hay insert y para cuando lo hay.

este es el codigo que tengo

> $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);

```
if ($resultado==null) {
    $rspta = "<script> bootbox.alert('No se pudo registrar porque ya existe el cliente');  </script>";
    //header("Location: ../vistas/crear_cliente.php");
} else {        
    $rspta = "<script> bootbox.alert('Se registró correctamente el cliente');  </script>";
    
    
}
echo ".$rspta.";
//header("Location: ../vistas/crear_cliente.php");
```

pd: uso "header("Location: ../vistas/crear_cliente.php");" para refrescar la pagina, si lo descomento no me tira el aviso de.

Comment: Creo que necesitas Javascript... si deseas mostrar un mensaje después de correr el código PhP, pues si refrescas, el código SQL no corre y no muestra nada... Hazme saber si deseas una respuesta con Javascript

Comment: por favor. Necesito un mensaje de confirmacion que me indique que se realizo el insert. Te lo agaradezco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhP se carga en servidor y luego es que envías una respuesta al navegador. Con simple PhP no puedes enviar un mensaje después que la página está cargada, necesitas un leguaje de cliente como Javascript. Lo que si puedes hace en este caso es:

```
if ($resultado==null) {
        
        ?> <!-- cerrar etiqueta de Php y elminar las comillas y los punto y coma de la etiqueta script y eliminar la variable -->

        <script> bootbox.alert('No se pudo registrar porque ya existe el cliente');  </script>
        
    <!-- abrimos Php de nuevo -->   
    
    <?Php
        //header("Location: ../vistas/crear_cliente.php");
    } else {   

?> <!-- cerrar etiqueta de Php y elminar las comillas y los punto y coma de la etiqueta script y eliminar la variable al igual que arriba -->   
        <script> bootbox.alert('Se registró correctamente el cliente');  </script>
     <!-- abrimos Php de nuevo -->  
    
    <?Php   
        
    }
    ?> <!-- cerramos Php de nuevo y eliminamos el resto, con esto ya debe todo de funcionar. -->
```

Te dejo el enlace con el código funcionando sin comentarios y donde puedes cambiar el valor de la variable `$resultado`.

https://paiza.io/projects/ughdSs-aq2ZecwX_O_g8ew

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: Perfecto, si te ha servido márcala como respuesta así le puede servir a otros como solución.

Comment: por supuesto, me has salvado

Comment: Éxitos hermano!